# Cauchy principal value and the "normal" definition.

Tags: improper-integrals

Suppose that $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(x)\, dx$ exist. How to prove that $\lim_{b\to\infty}\int^{b}_{-b}f(x)\, dx$ also exist, and  $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(x)\, dx=\lim_{b\to\infty}\int^{b}_{-b}f(x)\, dx$

Comment: How do you define the LHS? Is this lebesgue integral or riemmann integral?

Comment: *Riemann${}{}{}$

Comment: .....Riemann :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\, dx$ exist mean that both 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{0}f(x)\, dx,\,\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\, dx
$$

exist

This means that the two limits

$$
\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{-b}^{0}\, f(x)\, dx,\,\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{0}^{b}\, f(x)\, dx
$$

exist.

Since the two limits exists you can add them up and get the desired
result

Comment: I did that, but it seem to me too simple. Thanks!